# Release management does not support download of artifact type TfvcLabel in the current version

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

We are using TFS(Version 16.131.28106.2) to build and deploy the code.
I want to give source label On every Success build and Label format configured as `$(Build.SourceVersion)`.

I am getting Label from build definition as,

[image]

But, In Release definition, this gives me a warning message.
[image]

Artifacts for the Release definition is a Source(Build definition).

I have searched it and I found a [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/538a6eda-61bb-47a3-b4fb-4d37eddf2127/quotrelease-management-does-not-support-download-of-artifact-type-tfvclabel-in-the-current?forum=tfsbuild) with a similar Issue but Not answered.

Please help to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

​I had the same problem when deploying to a web site using Azure DevOps.

Checking "Skip download of artifacts" removed a similar warning.

​2020-01-31T11:49:21.9056366Z 147 MB downloaded at 29739 KB/sec. Download time: 00:00:05.0370218.
​2020-01-31T11:49:21.9056631Z Preparing to download artifact: build.SourceLabel
​
2020-01-31T11:49:21.9085798Z ##[warning]Release management does not support download of artifact type GitRef in the current version

[image]